# How can I configure JMeter elements and generate report

Tags: timer, jmeter, report

I can't configure JMeter elements and respeective report for an Web Service as per below definitions. Would you please suggest me the details about timer configuration and respective report for two definitions seperately please.

**Definition 1:** How many txn your system can respond in <= 10 seconds if sent in 1 min ( one time).
**Definition 2:** No. of txn with response <= 10 seconds if sent in interval of 60 seconds for 10 mins.

I can configure request parameter and other details, but I need how to implement only my mentioned definition and it's report.

Answer (score 0):

In current form your requirements don't make a lot of sense so I cannot provide a comprehensive answer covering all of them.

If I break your "defitions" into "pieces"

- `How many txn your system can respond` - you need to conduct a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing). Start with 1 thread (virtual user) and [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) at the same time looking at [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) and [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) charts. When you see that response time starts growing and throughput stops growing it means that the system reached maximum throughput. Check how many users were online just before that moment and run your test for 10 minutes - this way you will get the number of requests which system can process at the highest speed.
- `one time` - if you want to release all threads at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
- `sent in interval of 60 seconds`  - if you want to introduce a delay between requests take a look at [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri T, everything is okay. I wanted to set a scenario by this setup:  No. of thread-1, Ramp Up-1 sec, Loop count- Forever, Scheduler - 600 sec(10 minutes), Startup delay - 0. The loop will be continued for up to 10 minutes and I want to set a delay 1 minute after another. Like 0 - 1 minute continued, 1-2 minutes lopp paused, 2-3 minutes continued, 3-4 paused, 4-5 minutes continued......I have tried with **Constant Timer** & **Flow Control Action** but it paused after every sampler execution. I want a sampler will be executed one munute then pause for 1 minute such upto 10 minutes.